# How to add custom action button in suiteCRM module sub panel list?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need some suggestion in my suite CRM module integration.
I have a sub-panel in one of my modules and required to add one more edit button to redirect to a custom form to take some input from the user for each row separately.

Below is a sample image of my sub-panel list view.

[image: In this image on click of the edit button of a row there is a remove button, I want to add one more custom button after remove and need to redirect from there to my new form]

In the above image on click of the edit button of a row, there is a remove button, I want to add one more custom button after remove and need to redirect from there to my new form.

I have checked some of forums and blogs but didn't found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a button you will need to modify the metadata of that sub-panel. In metadata, you will see the following code for the `Edit` and `Remove` buttons:

```
 'edit_button' => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'LBL_EDIT_BUTTON',
    'widget_class' => 'SubPanelEditButton',
    'module' => 'Contacts',
    'width' => '5%',
    'default' => true,
  ),
  'remove_button' => 
  array (
    'vname' => 'LBL_REMOVE',
    'widget_class' => 'SubPanelRemoveButton',
    'module' => 'Contacts',
    'width' => '5%',
    'default' => true,
  ),
```

You can add your new button using same array syntax. As you can see that every button use specific widget class(defined as `widget_class`) therefore you will need to add new widget_class class for that. You can find existing widget classes in this folder: `include/generic/SugarWidgets`.

Cheers!

Comment: it is possible sir to add it in custom so that it will become upgrade/update safe?